# Cento OS + Direct Admin, how can I set a Forwarder to allow :fail: for a specific email address?

Tags: centos, centos7

I'm in need of creating a forward that will return an error message to whoever sends a message to an email address, the only problem is that I don't know how to that for specific emails and I haven't found a tutorial online teaching how to.
Let's say I have a noreply@domain.com email, which command line should I use to set a forward for that specific email address only? This way if someone sends a message to that email, the message won't arrive and the person will receive a reply like "This is an automatic message, the following recipient doesn't accept any incoming messages. "